# 1950s Children's TV Sci-Fi Where the Villain is an Arrangement of Crystals That Achieved Consciousness

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am trying to locate the name of a serialized children's sci-fi program.

My most vivid memory is the ending. The bad guy turned out to be a half dozen crystals whose positions relative to each other allowed it to achieve consciousness. The hero "killed" the villain by just moving one of the crystals. I don't remember if this plot/ending was for the whole series, or just one episode of the series.

Vague recollections (that might be wrong):

- It was a 10-minute segment of a half hour children's program.
- It might have had something to do with Crusader Rabbit, Sheriff John or Engineer Bill.
- It aired on a local Los Angeles TV station in the 1950s.
- It might have been stop motion animation.
- It was black and white.
- Low production value.

Answer (score 2):

This might be *The Space Explorers* (1958), which was serialized on Sheriff John's TV show in LA (I saw it in the early 1960s). It involves a boy and a scientist-astronaut who are looking for the boy's father, who is lost in space. I'm not sure about the ending or the crystals, though - I missed the last episode! Anyway, it was cobbled together from no less than three foreign (2 Russian, 1 German) movies & dubbed into English to take advantage of the Space Race. Most it was traditional animation, although the spaceflight scenes consisted of some pretty good model-work from the German film *Space Ship Takeoff, a Technical Fantasy*, 1938, which can be seen on Youtube.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this. I quickly checked it out online. Even if this turns out not to be what I'm searching for, I'm going to check it out thoroughly as, one way or other, it's probably part of my childhood.